Which "heroes on both sides" were intended to be referenced in "Revenge of the Sith"?
The opening crawl of Revenge of the Sith begins as follows:

War! The Republic is crumbling under attack by the ruthless Sith Lord, Count Dooku. There are heroes on both sides. Evil is everywhere.

Much later media, including the titular episode, would show us relatively heroic members of the Trade Federation and the Confederacy of Independent Systems, such as Lux Bonteri, but at the time, the most prominent Separatists included Count Dooku (a "ruthless Sith Lord," not a hero), General Grievous (known more for being a warlord and laughing evilly than for his heroism), the various heads of the Trade Federation (slimy profiteers to the last), and countless cowardly, not-particularly-intelligent droids.
What heroes on the Separatist side were meant to be indicated by this line? Were any of them referenced in media prior to or roughly contemporaneous with Revenge of the Sith?

One side's hero is usually a villain to the other side, and vice versa.

@HorusKol - Yes, but this is Star Wars, where heroism and particularly villainy are not precisely subtle. The villains start with people for whom any number of deaths is a good price to pay for a few more credits, going through people for whom casual murder is the entire reason they signed up, all the way through people who literally worship hatred and suffering. If George Lucas wrote that, he meant that there were people on the Separatist side that he and the presumed audience would see as clearly heroic, not "Some Separatists think genocide against Republic planets is heroic."

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heroes_on_Both_Sides

@Valorum - I don't see that reposting a link from the question itself, which was mentioned in the context of the episode not being relevant due to having been written years after the fact, and thus not plausibly being what the line referenced, really helps.

"Heroes" doesn't imply any moral stance in this case. It means that there were famous people who were viewed as great fighters, impressive strategists, innovative technologists, or brave/dedicated.
In the case of Separatists, Siths, etc., heroic individuals rose to prominence by showing valor or steadfastness even if their actions aren't morally upright. Dedication to the cause and sacrifice are the qualities, rather than correctness and ethics / value system. Even advanced droids were sometimes seen as "heroes" for their prowess. You can look up Kalani.
The problem with the movie is that there's a disconnect – we never see these characters showing dedication or making sacrifices to support their Separatist dreams coming into reality. The closest we see is the Separatists getting slaughtered by Anakin with their last concerns being "we only wanted peace", meaning that even though they were fighting a war, they ultimately wanted liberation from what they saw as an exploitative and corrupt Republic. Underpinning this was Sidious pulling the strings in the shadows.
While all of this is explored quite a lot in the supplemental materials, the film does not show much of that, and rather chiefly a fight with the primary officer (Dooku) resulting in his early death and a hunt for Grievous who is notoriously spineless. I can see how that sentence falls flat to anyone just watching the movie and not consuming any of the other media. The main story is about Anakin's downfall and the fight between Jedi and Sith in the context of the war, and not really about any of these "heroes" on the Confederate side. The story was streamlined to accommodate this for audiences who weren't familiar with any of these characters simplified into a good vs evil movie where dooku and grievous are the villainous archetypes, and more morally complex and interesting characters like Asajj, Nexu, etc. are notably absent. It would be too much to put into the trilogy on top of the other central narrative about Palpatine's plan for hegemony and Anakin's fall from grace: like Padme falling in love; the Kamino investigation; the discovery of the Separatists' army creation, the war starting on geonosis, the initial faceoff between the Jedi and dooku, the formation of the Grand Army; Anakin's isolation and premonitions of padme's death, Palpatine's manipulation of and insemination of ideas into Anakin; Anakin's killing of dooku; the destruction of Grievous. All of these things leading to his betrayal of mace windu and the jedi order in conjunction with order 66. These were the main plot ideas that the production crew wanted to conv since it's supposed to be a tragic tale of his descent to darkness. The decision comes at the expense of making the antagonists less compelling, empathetic, or fascinating, and many of them we never see do much of anything, if they're even there at al.
Other examples:

Mar Tuuk, strategic savant
Mina Bonteri, political advocate
Lok Durd, technologist
Riff Tamson, brutal combat

All of these had reason to war, though the exploration of Separatist characters, their talents and their complexity is largely relegated to the extended Star Wars universe through other media.

This assertion seems kind of speculative, particularly in light of the moral binary of the Star Wars universe. If you can find some evidence of George Lucas ever referring to a courageous but morally reprehensible person as heroic, that might help. And the examples given are not contemporaneous with or prior to the film.

So talking about characters like Asajj Ventress from media released years after that episode kind of is not addressing the most important part of the question.
